# Django: FieldError cannot resolve keyword '___' into a field

Tags: python, database, django, django-admin

I'm having a `FieldError`.

I have a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    __bar = models.TextField(default=lambda: cPickle.dumps(set()), primary_key=True)

    def get_bar(self):
        return cPickle.loads(str(self.__bar))

    def set_bar(self, values):
        self.__bar = cPickle.dumps(values)

    bar = property(get_bar, set_bar)
```

I have registered it with the admin in **admin.py**:

```
admin.site.register(Foo)
```

When I runserver and go to /admin, I see Foo in the list. If I click "Add", it works fine, showing the form to add a new Foo. However, if I click "save and add another" or "change" or "Foos", I get a `FieldError`

```
FieldError at /admin/appname/Foo/

Cannot resolve keyword '_Foo' into field. Choices are: _Foo__bar, appname
```

The traceback is:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/appname/foo/
Django Version: 1.2.4
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'pagination',
 'apps.appname']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  265.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  78.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  190.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  21.             return decorator(bound_func)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  17.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1097.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  80.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  271.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  677.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  722.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  57.         ordering, ordering_group_by = self.get_ordering()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in get_ordering
  346.                         self.query.model._meta, default_order=asc):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in find_ordering_name
  375.                 opts, alias, False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in setup_joins
  1215.                             "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/appname/foo/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword '_Foo' into field. Choices are: _Foo__bar, appname
```

What could be going on here? I did some searching, and I found similar errors but they seem to have something to do with many-to-many fields, of which I have none. There are other models that reference this one as a foreign key, but that seems unlikely to cause the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've prefixed `__bar` with two underscores, [Python is performing name mangling (doc link)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) in an attempt to enforce private access to the variable.

Private variables, of course, don't exist in Python, but by using the double-underscore convention you've asked Python to reformat `__bar` as `_(classname)__bar`, which is why Django is telling you that "`Choices are: _Foo__bar`...".

If you wish to signal that `bar` shouldn't be used outside out the class, I'd recommend the single-underscore notation (also discussed at the link above), which should solve the field issue you're experiencing as single-underscore prefixes are not name mangled.